# CanActivate route guard is not getting invoked

Tags: angular, angular-router, angular-router-guards

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { CanActivate, ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, CanActivateChild } from '@angular/router';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
    
@Injectable()
export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {
    
  constructor() { }
        
  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot): boolean | Observable<boolean> | Promise<boolean> {
    console.log("can activate called");
    return true;
  }
}

// route
const APP_ROUTES = [{
  path: 'login',
  CanActivate: [AuthGuardService],
  component: login
}
```

So when login page loads it's not invoking can activate method and printing console. I have created a guard service and added CanActivate property in routes.

Comment: By not using a strong type to define APP_ROUTES you are shooting yourself on the foot.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you have an capital C letter in `canActivate` in your app-routes.
Make sure you have registered your `AuthGuardService` in app.module.ts providers array.

Comment: Compiling is possible, because `canActivate` is an optional member of the `Route` interface and `CanAcivate` just gets ignored at this point.

Comment: \*\*facepalm\*\* ...Thx